# Kann ein Haus "schwer zu pflegen" bzw. "pflegearm" sein?

Tags: word-choice

Kann man sagen, dass ein Anwesen, ein Hof oder ein Haus schwer zu pflegen sind? Z.B

> Da das Haus ***schwer zu pflegen*** war, mussten wir es verkaufen. Wir kauften uns dann eine kleine Villa und da die in der Stadt liegt, ist sie ***pflegearm***

Comment: Üblicherweise wird man für Gebäude "unterhalten" verwenden.

Comment: "Pflegearm" scheint mir eine Neuschöpfung zu sein. Etabliert ist das Wort "pflegeleicht". Es wird zwar in der Regel für Textilien verwendet, doch könnte man es mit kreativem Sprachgebrauch auch auf andere Dinge anwenden.

Comment: Bei Maschinen o.ä. kann man auch _wartungsarm_ verwenden.

Comment: Kannst du noch erläutern, warum das Haus auf dem Land schwerer zu pflegen ist als das in der Stadt? - Das könnte Einfluss auf die Wortwahl haben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wenn es um Gebäude (oder auch Maschinen ö.Ä.) geht, verwendet man *instand halten* (auch: *in Stand halten*).

Eine andere Möglichkeit ist *unterhalten*, wie schon angemerkt.

> Das Haus ist schwer instand zu halten.

Es gibt noch viele andere mögliche Formulierungen, z.B.:

> Die Instandhaltung des Hauses ist aufwändig.

Das Gegenteil kann man entsprechend am einfachsten ausdrücken mit:

> Das Haus ist leicht instand zu halten.

Comment: Für mein Verständnis ist das Instandhalten eines Hauses etwas anderes als es der Fragesteller im Sinne hatte. Man weiß es ja nicht genau, aber aus der Frage scheint mir hervorzugehen, dass es um leichtere Arbeiten in Haus und Garten geht; vermutlich weil das Grundstück sehr groß ist; in der Stadt ist es sicherlich kleiner. "Instandhaltung" ist für mich verbunden mit aufwendigeren Bau- und Handwerksarbeiten an Haus. Diese wären im aber Stadthaus nicht anders als im Landhaus. Der Unterschied kann eigentlich nur im Garten liegen, und da spricht man nicht von "instandhalten".

Comment: Wenn es im vorliegenden Fall vorrangig um den Garten geht, kann man tatsächlich von Pflege reden. In dem Fall kann wohl man auch das Haus einbeziehen und von der Pflege von Haus und Garten sprechen. Aber ein Haus alleine kann man nicht pflegen, zumindest hört es sich nicht gut an.

Answer (score 3):

Wie sich aus der Diskussion zur Eingangsfrage und zu RHas Antwort zeigt, gibt es ein kleines Problem mit dem Wort "instandhalten" - das ja durchaus erst einmal erste Wahl wäre für die diversen Tätigkeiten baulich-handwerklichen Charakters, die dazu dienen, die Spuren, die der Zahn der Zeit an einem Gebäude hinterlässt, auszubügeln, und alles funktionsfähig zu halten.

Das Problem ist, dass im unterstellten Szenario eher der Garten als das Haus die viele Arbeit machte ("aufwendig zu pflegen" war). Wenn es nun aber vor allem um den Garten geht, dann ist "instandhalten" kein gutes Wort dafür.

Außerdem bezöge sich "instandhalten" auf größere, handwerkliche Arbeiten.

Was könnte man aber sagen, wenn man Tätigkeiten meint, die rund um Haus und Garten anfallen und die viel Arbeit machen können, ohne dass damit die eigentliche (technische, bauliche) *Instandhaltung* gemeint ist?

> Es war zu viel Arbeit, das Anwesen **in Schuss zu halten**, darum haben wir es verkauft und uns was in der Stadt gesucht, das nicht so viel Arbeit macht.

Einschränkung: Das ist ein guter Ausdruck in mündlicher Sprache, nicht geeignet aber für schriftliche Äußerungen in formalen Kontexten.

Du könntest deinen Satz auch so umformulieren.

> Da das Haus **zu viel Arbeit machte**, mussten wir es verkaufen. Wir kauften uns dann eine kleine Villa, und da sie in der Stadt liegt, ist sie pflegeleicht.

---

Nebenthema: Das Wort "Villa" evoziert im Deutschen das Bild eines großen, tendenziell großbürgerlichen Hauses mit zwei bis drei Etagen und viel Garten (wenn auch typischerweise in einem Teil der Stadt gelegen, der früher einmal Stadtrand war). Im Kontrast mit dem (einfachen) "Haus" auf dem Land sollte man meinen, der Aufwand für Pflege und Unterhalt sei sogar größer. - Es gibt jedoch europäische Sprachen, in denen "Villa" (diverse Schreibweisen) kein repräsentatives Stadthaus meint sondern ein Ferienhäuschen oder Wochenendhäuschen (Datscha).